# Can I get a sum of master and a sum of a detail in one sql statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a master / detail table arrangement (one to many) and I want  a total of a master field and a total of a detail field.

Do I have to run 2 sql statments or can I combine them efficiently into one statement and still not get duplicate sum of the master value?

Sample:

```
orders:
customer_id int,
order_id int,
order_amount int

details:
customer_id int,
order_id int,
detail_amount int


SELECT sum(order_amount), sum(detail_amount) FROM orders m
JOIN details d on d.order_id = m.order_id
WHERE customer_id = 123;

the results will be incorrect when orders exist with multiple details.

I can: 
SELECT sum(order_amount) FROM orders m
WHERE customer_id = 123;

and 

SELECT sum(detail_amount) FROM details d 
WHERE customer_id = 123;
```

can I combine them efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do with a subquery.

```
SELECT sum(order_amount) as orderTotal, (SELECT sum(detail_amount) FROM details d 
WHERE d.customer_id = m.customer_id) as detailTotal FROM orders m
WHERE customer_id = 123;
```

Comment: hmm that doesn't give me the correct answer.  it's doesn't seem to be getting all the details for all the masters - I may have set some thing up wrong

Comment: Did it work for you with the individual queries?  If so, this should return the same answer.

Comment: It seems to only give the detail sum of the last order, not all orders for a customer

Comment: I am guessing you are having some other sort of issue.  If you run the individual queries you had above, did they work?

Comment: individually, I get the correct answer, combined I don't. probably my error